# Barrier maintaining the order of threads flow after being open (java multithreading)

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

Let's assume, that there is a constant flow of threads going through my java code. I would like to stop them in such way, that when a certain flag is changed, all threads will wait on some barrier and then (when the flag is changed again) resume in the same order in which they reached the barrier *before* all the threads that will come in the meantime. In other words: constant flow of threads, I would like to stop them and then resume in such way that in my flow the order of threads will stay the same. I thought about such solution:

I declare those variables in some part of my code (that block of code is run by one thread):

```
...
Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(0, true)
atomicBoolean flag = new atomicBoolean(flase);
atomicInteger threadCounter = new atomicInteger(0);
...
```

Here is my barrier that should count and stop all the threads (that block of code is run by multiple threads):

```
if(flag.compareAndSet(false, false)) {
threadCounter.addAndGet(1);
mutex.acquire();
}
```

Then, I would like the threads to resume in the same order in which they reach the barrier, so I do:

```
        ...
flag.set(true);
for(threadCounter) {
   mutex.realise();
}
        ...
```

That should release threads from my mutex semaphore in the right order. HOWEVER I had to change my flag, so all the threads that pass thought the barrier will mix with threads released from mutex semaphore!

I can do it like that:

```
        ...
for(threadCounter) {
   mutex.realise();
}
flag.set(true);
        ...
```

But, if I put my flag on the other side of the loop, I will be left with some threads waiting on the barrier, because they can come after the end of the loop and before I change my flag.

Then what should I do? Any help would be much appreciated.